# Refresh parent window after submitting a form in a IFrame in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how can i refresh/reload parent window from an iframe on submit without closing the frame using javascript / jquery.
Parent window contains Display table and Button that opens an Iframe.
Iframe contains a form which on submit saves data in the table which is displayed on parent window.
At present data is not displayed until i refresh the page manually.
please Suggest me a method to do so.

This is the scenario

- main window has a buttton called form ,
- on clicking it an Iframe Opens ,
- Iframe has a Form which on submit saves data,
- this data is displayed in a table on the main window.

But when I do submit  data is saved but not displayed.

I want a method so that My Main window is refreshed / reloaded without having to close the Iframe and refreshing it manually

Please suggest a solution to this problem ...don't offer any other method..

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. You likely need to rethink the problem - AJAX would likely be what you need. In any case please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask here. HINT: Post code and effort

Comment: There is no code i want a suggestion to tackle this problem

Comment: Why use an iframe? Submit using AJAX - then you need only one page

Comment: I don't want to do that

Comment: If you do not want to use Ajax, you need to have the iFrame update parts of the parent using parent.document.getElementById("result").innerHTML for example. But if you do that, you might as well use Ajax. you cannot reload the parent page without reloading/losing the iFrame

Comment: I don't want to lose the Frame just to reload the frame and the page as well

Comment: As I suggested. update the parent page in the result of the iframe submit. - send `<script>parent.document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="whatever"</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing is Not Possible Parent window cannot be refreshed keeping open the I-frame